# How To Combine 2 SELECT Statements Using INNER JOIN Or UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, select, inner-join, union

I have a table named user and vaccine like below

**user**

| user_id | first_dose | second_dose |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A221H | MN03 | PF88 |
| C221G | SV05 | AZ51 |

**vaccine**

| vaccine_id | vaccine_name |
| --- | --- |
| MN03 | Moderna |
| SV05 | Sputnik V |
| PF88 | Pfizer |
| AZ51 | Astrazeneca |
| SN12 | Sinopharm |
| CNV7 | Convidecia |

What i want to achieve for 1st user is like below

| dose1_name | dose2_name |
| --- | --- |
| Moderna | Pfizer |

Here is the 1st approach i took (using only 1 INNER JOIN)

```
SELECT vaccine_name AS dose1_name, vaccine_name AS dose2_name FROM vaccine INNER JOIN user ON first_dose = vaccine.vaccine_id WHERE user.user_id = 'A221H'
```

But it gives output like this

| dose1_name | dose2_name |
| --- | --- |
| Moderna | Moderna |

The 2nd approach i took (using INNER JOIN 2 times)

```
SELECT vac_name AS dose1_name, vac_name AS dose2_name FROM vaccine INNER JOIN user fd ON fd.first_dose = vaccine.vaccines_id INNER JOIN user sd ON sd.second_dose = vaccine.vaccines_id  WHERE fd.user_id = 'A221H' AND sd.user_id = 'A221H'
```

But it gives no output

| dose1_name | dose2_name |
| --- | --- |
| - | - |

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your second query is about right, although you should start with User table and then join to Vaccine tables. Do you actually have any records matching the criteria in the WHERE clause?

Comment: I've checked and did some typo it supposed to be fd.user_id and sd.user_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative is to use a *correlated subquery* for each required join:

```
select User_Id,
    (select vaccine_name from vaccine v where v.vaccine_id = u.first_dose) as dose1_name,
    (select vaccine_name from vaccine v where v.vaccine_id = u.second_dose) as dose2_name
from user u;
```

you may also need to *coalesce* the columns if both doses are not always populated.

Comment: I've tried this method and it worked smoothly *don't know that SELECT can be stacked this way*, by the way what do you mean by coalescing the column?

Comment: I mean if a user does not have a first and/or second dose populated you can use `coalesce()` to provide a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach of 2 joins is correct, however as a comment on your post mentioned, it should be the users table and then 2 left joins to the vaccine tables

For example:

```
SELECT vac1.vaccine_name as dose1_name, vac2.vaccine_name as dose2_name
FROM user
LEFT JOIN vaccine as vac1 ON user.first_dose = vac1.vaccine_id
LEFT JOIN vaccine as vac2 ON user.second_dose = vac2.vaccine_id
WHERE user.user_id = 'XXXX'
```

Comment: This is the way! p.s. check for typos, you've mentioned left joins but have inenr joins, second one should be using `vac2.vaccine_id`

Comment: @SilviuBurcea you are correct! edited the typos

Comment: I got an error saying that there is not vaccine_name in user field, is it supposed to be vaccine.vaccine_name FROM vaccine?

Comment: you do not select the vaccine_name form user tho, its from vac1/vac2 which is actually the vaccine table

Comment: You're right i didn't know that JOIN can works like that, now your method is also working by fixing some typo. Great job